# Render string containing JSX in react binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've found a lot of questions that are similar to this but none that actually answer my question.

I have a string that contains a JSX template to create a link and need to render this in the binding within a `Text` component. Below I have some same text so you can see approximately what I have.

Currently `{content}` will render as `This string has JSX: [Object, object]`. How do I make it actually render `FAQLink`.

**What I've tried**

I've tried using `<React.Fragment>{content}<React.Fragment>` with no luck.

```
function TooltipContent() {
 const FAQLink = () => (
  <Link
    color="teal40"
    hoverColor="teal30"
    underlined
    to={paths.resourcePage({ slug: 'frequently-asked-questions' })}
  >
    FAQ
  </Link>
 );

 const contentArray = [
  `This string has JSX: ${<FAQLink />}`,
  `Another possible string`
 ];

 let content;
 if (variant === 'risk') {
  content = contentArray[0];
 } else {
  content = contentArray[1];
 }

 return (
  <Text textAlign="left" p={2}>
    {content}
  </Text>
 );
}
```

**This code does work but isn't possible for my case**

```
function TooltipContent() {
 const FAQLink = () => (
  <Link
    color="teal40"
    hoverColor="teal30"
    underlined
    to={paths.resourcePage({ slug: 'frequently-asked-questions' })}
  >
    FAQ
  </Link>
 );

 return (
  <Text textAlign="left" p={2}>
    This string has JSX: <FAQLink />
  </Text>
 );
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the second option "not possible"? The second option is the right way to go about this.

Comment: I'll update the code example so you can see.

Comment: @goto1 I updated the code example above. The text that can show up in `{content}` is conditional based on another var that is passed in.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why it has to be stored in a string? For example, why can't it be something like `content = <>I am a teapot! <FAQLink /></>`? And why does it have to be stored in an `array`?

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't need to be a string or in an array. `content = <>I am a teapot! <FAQLink /></>` worked. Please post as an answer and I will accept. Can't believe I didn't think of that. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `template literals` won't work with `React` components.

However, you could utilize `React.Fragment` to accomplish what you need, like in the following example:

```js
function TooltipContent(props) {
  const { variant = "default" } = props;
  const FAQLink = () => <a href="https://google.com">I am a link!</a>;

  let content;

  switch (variant) {
    case "risk":
      content = (
        <React.Fragment>
          RISK! <br />
          <FAQLink />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
      break;
    case "no-risk":
      content = "NO RISK";
      break;
    default:
      content = variant;
  }
  return <p>{content}</p>;
}
```

Here's a working example:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-perlman-ucoqs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `JSX` is just sugar syntax for React functions.
Your code `transpiles` like this:

```
"use strict";

function TooltipContent() {
  var FAQLink = function FAQLink() {
    return React.createElement(Link, {
      color: "teal40",
      hoverColor: "teal30",
      underlined: true,
      to: paths.resourcePage({
        slug: 'frequently-asked-questions'
      })
    }, "FAQ");
  };

  var content = "This string has JSX: ".concat(React.createElement(FAQLink, null));
  return React.createElement(Text, {
    textAlign: "left",
    p: 2
  }, content);
}
```

So that `concat` function, or the `${}` syntax, just converts your React elements (that is an `object`) into a `string`, but this results in `[Object object]`.

What you are trying to do, in this way, will always give you this result.
Can you explain why you have to do this and you can not do in the other way?

Comment: I updated my code example above to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do. Looks like I may need to rethink how to accomplish my conditional strings. Any help is greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wants to render FAQLink as a code example, If yes here is code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/render-jsx-text-u480p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Please, do not answer with a link. If the source is removed or changed that link the answer will be obsolete.
Can you explain to the user how to do it in the answer or add an example?
Thanks.